# Setting Date to editText using Date picker

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I want to set two different Date(s) to two different EditText(s) using datePickerDialog. i am using two different String objects to store date and then setting them on two different EditText(s) respectively but the problem is both the EditText(s) are taking same values.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    // Get the calander
    java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    // From calander get the year, month, day, hour, minute
    int year = c.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    switch (id) {
        case Date_from:

            // Open the datepicker dialog
            return new DatePickerDialog(WastageRecordsByDateActivity.this, date_listener, year,
                    month, day);
        case Date_to:

            return new DatePickerDialog(WastageRecordsByDateActivity.this, date_listener, year,
                    month, day);
    }
    return null;
}

// Date picker dialog
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date_listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // store the data in one string and set it to edittext
        String date1 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
        editTextFrom.setText(date1);

        String date2 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
        editTextTo.setText(date2);
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its happening because your both Strings object are having same data , that is coming from method. What you are doing is just saving that data on different objects, but data is same.

```
 String date1 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
        editTextFrom.setText(date1);

 String date2 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
        editTextTo.setText(date2);
```

Comment: how can i store date on different objects?

Comment: Try different methods for different objects.

Comment: i created different 'DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener' object and it worked for me. thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you are setting same value to both the editText as shown below,

```
        String date1 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
        editTextFrom.setText(date1);

        String date2 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
        editTextTo.setText(date2);
```

As we don't have the whole source code of yours, but you can trya little patch here, you can pass another arg Boolean,

```
    switch (id) {
            case Date_from:

                // Open the datepicker dialog
                return new DatePickerDialog(WastageRecordsByDateActivity.this, date_listener, year,
                        month, day, true);
            case Date_to:

                return new DatePickerDialog(WastageRecordsByDateActivity.this, date_listener, year,
                        month, day, false);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Date picker dialog
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date_listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day, Boolean stat) {
            // store the data in one string and set it to edittext
            if(stat==true){
                String date1 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                    + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
                editTextFrom.setText(date1);
            }
            if(stat==false){
                 String date2 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                    + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
                 editTextTo.setText(date2);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
switch (id) {
        case Date_from:

            // Open the datepicker dialog
            return new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
String date1 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
        editTextFrom.setText(date1);
                        }
                    }, 2017, 04, 25);
        case Date_to:

            return new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                            String date2 = String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month + 1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
                         editTextTo.setText(date2);
                        }
                    }, 2017, 04, 25);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try This and Let me know bro,

```
    edtxt1a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtxt1a.getWindowToken(), 0);

                showDispatchCalendar();

            }
        });


        private void showDispatchCalendar() {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog da = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mDateSetListener, sYearIni, sMonthIni, sDayIni);
        c1.add(DATE, 0);
        Date newDate = c1.getTime();
        da.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime());

        da.show();

    }

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYearIni = year;
                    mMonthIni = monthOfYear;
                    mDayIni = dayOfMonth;

                    colocar_fecha();
                }
            };


            private void colocar_fecha() {

        day1 = mDayIni;
        month1 = mMonthIni + 1;
        year1 = mYearIni;
        edtxt2a.setEnabled(true);
        edtxt2a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border_edittext);
        edtxt1a.setText(day1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + year1 + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for coming up with solution but this guy @Abdul Kawee solved the problem for me in first place.